# Jquery disable function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function myfunction(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        alert();
    });
}

myfunction();

$('#x').off('click', myfunction);//click disable myfunction();

<button></button>
<span id='x'></span>
```

I need to disable function, I have try jquery off, but its not working

can anyone tell me how? and how to enable again?

Comment: What do you want exactly? It is not clear from your description.

Comment: when #x click, disable myfunction()

Comment: What is `'#x'`, and which function exactly are you trying to disable?  Are you trying to toggle the 'click' handler function?

Comment: I guess you want when #x clicked, button click should not work?

Comment: yes, #x clicked, myfunction(); will disable

Comment: You need to attach the executed callback to the clickhandler via [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Then you can use off like you did in your example…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What, exactly, do you expect this to do?:

```
$('#x').off('click', myfunction);
```

Assuming for a moment that `#x` is a subset of `button`, you never actually set `myfunction` as a handler on `button` in the first place.  You set an anonymous function:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    alert();
});
```

If you want to "disable" that function (that is, remove the click handler from your element), then make it a non-anonymous function and remove the handler:

```
function myfunction () {
    alert();
}

$('button').on('click', myfunction);

$('#x').off('click', myfunction);
```

Or, if you're just going to do this once and trying to set the handler on all elements except that one, just omit it from your selector:

```
$('button').not('#x').on('click', myfunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add one variable like isDisabled = false;
Check that variable at the begining of the MyFunction().
And set that variable to true when #x clicked.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Internet Explorer with function attr() e prop()... when use disable attribuite..
See here for complete solution:
https://lentux-informatica.com/bug-jquery-disable-e-internet-explorer-soluzione/